# Tricky simultaneous Equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

Given the simultaneous equations
$$
x + yz = y + zx = z + xy
$$

and

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2  =  6$$

show that $x = 1$ or $y = z$ and hence solve the equations.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This second equality can be written $(x-1)(y-z)=0$. Then with $x=1$, the first becomes $(y-1)(z-1)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$z+yz=t,y+zx=t,z+xy=t$$ and we get (from the last equation) $$z=t-xy$$, using this in (1) and (2)
$$x+y(t-xy)=t$$
$$y+x(t-xy)=t$$
solving the last equation for $y$:
$$y(1-x^2)=t(1-x)$$
Can you proceed?
Factorizing:
$$(1-x)(y(1+x)-t)=0$$
Substituting $x=1$ into the system:
$$1+yz=y+z$$ or $$(1-z)(1-y)=0$$

Comment: I got this far but do not understand why y = z ?

Comment: Doh ! I could look but I did not see this !

Comment: Ok, i did it for you!